# how to hide a text field in js?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to hide the text field when I select from *item2* from the list. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Select Parent</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="parent_id" class="span6 m-wrap" data-placeholder="Choose a Parent" tabindex="1">
            <option value="0" >Select Parent</option>
            <?php
                $admin_sql=mysql_query("select * from admin_detail where parent_id='0' and role='2'");
                while($Fetch_Admin=mysql_fetch_array($admin_sql)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $Fetch_Admin['id']; ?>" onClick = "myFunction()"  > <?php echo $Fetch_Admin['name'] ;?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="span6 m-wrap"  placeholder="Name" required/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Login ID</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="login" class="span6 m-wrap"   placeholder="Login ID" required/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="span6 m-wrap"   placeholder="Password" required/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" id="op1">
    <label class="control-label" >Add Options</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text"  name="option1"  class="span6 m-wrap"  placeholder="Option1" required/>
        <input type="text"  name="option2"  class="span6 m-wrap"  placeholder="Option2" required/>
        <input type="text"  name="option3"  class="span6 m-wrap"  placeholder="Option3" required/>
        <input type="text"  name="option4"  class="span6 m-wrap"  placeholder="Option4" required/>
        <input type="text"  name="option5"  class="span6 m-wrap"  placeholder="Option5" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The associated javascript function is:

```
<script> function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("op1").style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
```

I have also tried the same thing by using a button. When I apply the `onClick` function to the button it work properly. Can some one show me where I am going wrong or which function should I use for the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've placed your event handler in an `onclick` attribute of an `<option>` element. This probably isn't going to work as intended. Instead, add an `onchange` event handler to its parent `<select>` element as follows:

```
<select name="parent_id" ... onchange="document.getElementById('op1').style.visibility=(this.selectedIndex==2)?'hidden':'visible';">
```

Comment: onclick should work when you will click on that particlular option in which it is declared .i cant see any reason for it to not working.

Comment: Suppose you navigate to the `<select>` element by pressing the tab key and use the up/down/enter keys to change its value. Would the `onclick` handler do anything then?

Comment: that is an exception case but as a programmer we should be prepared for the worst case.so +1 for this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById("op1").style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`document.getElementById("op1").style.display="none";`

instead of:

`document.getElementById("op1").style.visibility="hidden";`

Comment: Visibility hidden is a valid CSS attribute. It just makes the thing invisible but keeps its place in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

For a list like the one you have it is required to add the event handling on the select element.

```
    <select name="parent_id" id="parent_id" class="span6 m-wrap" data-placeholder="Choose a Parent" tabindex="1" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="0" >Select Parent</option>
  <option value="item2" > item2 </option>
    </select>
```

Then your js code could be like,

```
function myFunction()
{
    if(document.getElementById("parent_id").value=="item2"){
document.getElementById("op1").style.visibility="hidden";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("op1").style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
```

Example,
http://jsfiddle.net/5E8AH/

Also, the difference between *display:block* and *visibility:hidden* is that the latter will hide the content but still take the space as if it were visible.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
document.getElementById("op1").style.display="none";
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive .please use proper camelcase

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = "none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "hidden";
```